# How do I use React classes now in Ruby on Rails with WebPack

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

So I followed [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails) tutorial to understand the react syntax using it on Ruby on Rails and got it pretty well, just javascript, then I tried to implement webpack from this [other](https://medium.com/@hpux/rails-5-1-loves-javascript-a1d84d5318b) tutorial but the thing I noticed is that, the .jsx components has a very different syntax, also I tried to copy-paste my components from the first tutorial and doesn't work, `React.createClass` is no longer and now I don't know how to nest `.jsx` like in the first tutorial, I don't know if it is a different kind of React or where can I find examples

Comment: Could you please clarify? What do you mean nest? Do you mean include other JSX elements in JSX?

Comment: Yes, try to include a jsx into another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSX syntax can be a little confusing at first, but it'll become second nature soon enough. Let's say you have the react component `List`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Item from "./item";

export default class List extends React.Component {
    render(props) {
        return <ol>{props.list.map( item => <Item item={item}> )}</ol>
    }
}
```

Notice the line that `import`s Item. Once you've imported your component like that, you render it exactly like you would a normal HTML element. Does this answer your question?